# multicast id in firebase cloud messaging service

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

What is the multicast_id in Firebase cloud messaging service?

As mentioned in the documentation that is provided by Google, multicast id is the unique number that identifies the multicast message.

I read it, but I did not understand it clearly.
Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 2):

Per [Firebase Cloud Messaging HTTP Protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#interpret-downstream) documentation:

The **multicast_id** is a required parameter in the FCM response payload, and is a unique ID that identifies the multicast message.

A **multicast message** is a notification that will be sent from a server and targeting multiple client applications.

To answer your question directly, this response parameter is just an identification ID of a multicast message sent to client applications.

I'm not sure yet, but looking at the [Build App Server Send Requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message) documentation, you will only get this response parameter when you use Single Device Messaging targeting a single or array of registration tokens.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Can u please elaborate more?

Comment: better  to use FCM statistics [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en),If you want to use it for delivery status of the message sent.

Answer (score 0):

On a simpler note, a `multicast_id` is similar (if not identical enough) to a `message_id`.

In addition to [looptheloop88's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44589548/4625829), the usual purpose of both the `message_id` and `multicast_id` is for tracking/logging. As I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41710960/4625829):

> There is currently no available API to make use of the `message_ids`/`multicast_ids` to retrieve the details of the delivery status of the message sent, other than using the [FCM Diagnostics Page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en).