# FCM ,check for successful delivery

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I create java rest api service, I need to make push notifications to android devices , my code is

```
Pushraven.setKey("KEy");
        Notification raven = new Notification();
        raven.title(title)
             .text(message)
             .color("#ff0000")
             .to("User token");              
        FcmResponse response = Pushraven.push(raven);
        Pushraven.setNotification(raven);
        System.out.println("Respose: "+response.getResponseCode());
        raven.clear();
```

The question is, how to check is my notifications brought to device successfully, `response.getResponseCode()` always return 200 but some times message doesn't come to device

Comment: What platform is the client?

Comment: android platform

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check the delivery status of Firebase message sent to an Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41700719/how-to-check-the-delivery-status-of-firebase-message-sent-to-an-android-applicat)