# Of what use is a Firebase Cloud Message Id?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

After running the following code

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import * as serviceAccount from "../../firebase_service_account_key.json";

const app = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount as any),
  databaseURL: "https://my-app.firebaseio.com"
});

const messaging = app.messaging();
export async function sendPushNotification(token: string, title: string, body: string) {
        const resp = await messaging.send({
            token,
            notification: {
                title,
                body,
            }
        });
        console.log(resp);
}
```

I get this output

> projects/choose-health-app/messages/0:1559686024913017%0b13c0ce0b13c0ce

It would appear the response is some type of id for the message that was just sent.  From this answer on Stack Overflow ([How to check the delivery status of Firebase message sent to an Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41700719/how-to-check-the-delivery-status-of-firebase-message-sent-to-an-android-applicat)) it would appear I can not use this id to track the state of the cloud message (which I would really like to do, because it's currently just disappearing into the void).  But I don't understand what the point of returning this ID would be if it can't be used to track it.

So what can I do with this cloud message id?  Of what use or value is it?  Just book-keeping?  I can't seem to find any way to use it to gain information, or fulfill the needs of some function.

EDIT: The reason I care is that right now this is the only information I have around a bug, and I just want to know as much as possible about it.